# How to access and change html from addon(Mozilla Addon SDK) main code?

Tags: mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

Need to access html content from main code so that i can replace certain strings/words with another string and display in the web page.I have tried sending the array of strings from the main code to content script. Then i used jquery in the content script to get html contents. (.html()). I then replaced strings using javascript replace method and returned the new html content to load in web page. But it didnt work1 Need some help

Comment: At what point doesn't it work? Is there an error message in the web console or browser console? Please show the code that reinjects HTML into the page. Have you considered a GreaseMonkey script instead of a full addon?

Comment: mainaddoncode:
            var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
            var self=require("sdk/self");
            var pageMod=require("sdk/page-mod");
            var str="to";
            pageMod.PageMod({
             include: "*",
                contentScriptWhen: "ready",
             contentScriptFile:[self.data.url("jquery-1.10.2.min.js"),self.data.url("script.js")],
                onAttach: function OnAttach(worker) {
              worker.port.emit("a",str);
                }  
            });

Comment: @YolandaRuiz script code:    
        self.port.on("a",function(s1){
         var s=s1;
         var h=$("body").html();
         var h1;
         h1=h.replace(s,"FILTERED");
         h=h1;
         $("body").html(h); 
        });

Comment: PLEASE JUST EDIT YOUR question with the example code, the question as-is is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

string `.replace()` method will only replace the first occurrence, try with this in your script code to replace all occurrences:

```
var h1 = h.replace(new RegExp(s, 'g'), 'FILTERED');
```

Please review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) for a more complete treatment of replacing all, in case your input has special characters or user input values. Since the replacement uses a regex to operate, you must be careful with the input value, and escape it properly if there is a chance that it contains regex meta characters.